# Unit Test before Nuget Publish in TFS 2013

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, nuget

I have a class library that I publish to our internal nuget server.  Inside of a MSBuild script, I use nuget.exe to publish it.  The project also has a comprehensive unit test assembly.  It seems that TFS uses the build script to build the project, deploys the nuget package, then runs the unit tests.  Obviously, this is less than ideal.  The unit tests should run first, then the deploy.

How would one configure TFS to do this?  Maybe a postbuild script that runs nuget.exe publish?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the TFS 2013 default build template, there are some baked in script entry points so you can execute custom steps in the TFS build process using powershell scripts so there is no need to customise the template itself for example - see this link for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx

In your case, you could remove the existing publish step you have in your msbuild script and move it to a new powershell script referenced in the 'post test script path' variable (i.e. it will be executed after the unit test phase)

Comment: Optionally make the MsBuild script a separate target and simply execute that target in the post-build entry point of team build. Remove it from the default build target execution.